# How to check if array contains at least one value meeting a criteria?

Tags: ruby

I have this array:

[0, 2, 1]

I need to determine if at least one value of this array is equal or greater than one
How can I solve that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Even a simplistic approach would work--have you considered iterating over the array and checking each element? It's probably best if you at least make an attempt. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: i've just tried something using any? { |size| size >= 0 }

Comment: I'm not sure how `n >= 0` meets the requirement of "equal or greater than one", but other than that, did it work?

Comment: The title of your question is unrelated to what you are asking inside the question. The title refers to the length of the array, but your question about its content.

Comment: @user1934428 In fairness, the title could be interpreted either way, but I can see the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

From what you commented before, using the *any?* method provided by Ruby [Enumerable](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any%3F) class would work.

The following snippet could solve your problem:

```
[0, 2, 1].any? { |elem| elem >= 1 }
```

producing the following outputs:

```
[0, 2, 1].any? { |elem| elem >= 1 } === true
[-3, -1, 0].any? { |elem| elem >= 1 } === false
[1, 0, 1].any? { |elem| elem >= 1 } === true
```